# why is count(), filter() and mutate() not working inside a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, count, tidyverse, summarize

I know this is a silly question, but still. **I'd like to *understand* why `count()` is not working inside this very simple for-loop**.

**EDIT2**

I solved using `ch_data$QUnlist <- unlist(Q)`. But I'd still like to know why it worked and if there's a better way

**EDIT1**

Now I'm having the same problem with `filter()` and `mutate()`

- Code with the error:

```
listDFs <- list()

for (i in 1:2) {
  
## select colums:
  
Q <- names(ch_data[, 1:2][i])

## put into dataframes: 
  
listDFs[[i]] <-  ch_data %>% 
                     dplyr::count(Q) %>% 
                  mutate(prop = round((prop.table(n) * 100), digits = 2),
                  sd = round(sd(prop.table(n)), digits = 2)) %>%
           arrange(Q)
  
}

Error in `dplyr::count()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
x Column `Q` is not found.


## edit ##

ch_data %>% 
select(Q) %>% 
 filter(!Q %in% 'Não oferta') %>% ## NOT WORKING
 count(!!!syms(Q)) %>% 
  mutate(prop = round((prop.table(n) * 100), digits = 2),
         sd = round(sd(prop.table(n)), digits = 2),
         CH = Q, ### NOT WORKING
         QUESTION = rep('mylabel', length(CH))) %>% select (-Q) %>%
  arrange(CH) %>% 
  relocate(QUESTION, CH, .before = everything())
```

- I've already tried:

A) Since I know that `count()` expects a dataframe, I've done `Q <- ch_data[, 1:2][i]` 
B) I thought that maybe the quotes were the problem, so I tried `str_glue('{noquote(Q)}')` inside `count()` but it didn't work too.

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600291/r-extract-data-frame-from-list-without-prefixes-in-column-names), but I couldn't work it out. Thanks in adv.

- the data with 2 variables 
  (it has more questions, but I wanted to make it simple):

```
dput(ch_data)
structure(list(Q29 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Não oferta", 
"1h - 3h", "Mais de 10h", "50% em LA", "100% em LA"), class = "factor"), 
    Q30 = structure(c(4L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("Não oferta", 
    "1h - 3h", "4h - 5h", "6h - 8h", "9h - 10h", "Mais de 10h", 
    "50% em LA", "100% em LA"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-51L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Q is not a colum in ch_data. You need to pass the column names to the count function.

Comment: but shouldn't it be ```Q29``` ? why isn't  ```Q <- names(ch_data[, 1:2][i])```  working?

Comment: Because when you just use count(Q), dplyr thinks : „oh, I have to search for the column name 'Q' in ch_data.“ but it won‘t find that column because in your case Q is a vector carrying the names that you want to analyze. See my provided answer.

Comment: @deschen , it worked for ```count```, but now I'm having the same problem with ```filter()``` and ```mutate()``` . Any ideas? I've added an edit to the post

Comment: I suggest you are reading up a bit on the philosophy of the tidyverse. Simply put, when using tidyverse functions/packages like dplyr, they assume that everything you are doing happens within your data object, e.g. that when you are passing a column name argument, it will find the column in your data. However, that‘s not true in your case. You are passing an object FROM OUTSIDE THE DATA carrying the names. To make that work, you can wrap the naming argumwnt in '!!sym()' or '!!!syms'()', depending on whether you are passing on or several values. In your case it‘s two columns, hence !!!syms.

Comment: See [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more details of what @deschen is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
ch_data %>%
  dplyr::count(!!!syms(Q))
```

Example:

```
Q <- names(ch_data[,1:2])

ch_data %>%
  count(!!!syms(Q))

                 Q29               Q30  n
1  N\303\243o oferta N\303\243o oferta 21
2  N\303\243o oferta           1h - 3h  9
3  N\303\243o oferta           4h - 5h  4
4  N\303\243o oferta           6h - 8h  1
5  N\303\243o oferta          9h - 10h  1
6  N\303\243o oferta       Mais de 10h  1
7  N\303\243o oferta         50% em LA  2
8  N\303\243o oferta        100% em LA  5
9            1h - 3h           1h - 3h  1
10           1h - 3h           4h - 5h  1
11       Mais de 10h       Mais de 10h  1
12         50% em LA         50% em LA  2
13        100% em LA          9h - 10h  1
14        100% em LA        100% em LA  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll be better off avoiding [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), in this case:

- First, turn into a long format.
- Second, do the calculations using grouping (you might not need `prop.table`)
- Third, split into the desired list.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) # Please update to v. >= 1.1.0

ch_data |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Q")) |>
  count(name, value) |>
  mutate(prop = round((prop.table(n) * 100), digits = 2),
         sd = round(sd(prop.table(n)), digits = 2),
         .by = name) |> # If dplyr v. < 1.1.0, use group_by()-notation
  group_split(name)
```

(You can remove "Não oferta" with filtering on `value` if you need and `arrange` on what-ever you need, e.g. `name` or `prop`.)

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  name  value           n  prop    sd
  <chr> <fct>       <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Q29   Não oferta     44 86.3   0.37
2 Q29   1h - 3h         2  3.92  0.37
3 Q29   Mais de 10h     1  1.96  0.37
4 Q29   50% em LA       2  3.92  0.37
5 Q29   100% em LA      2  3.92  0.37

[[2]]
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  name  value           n  prop    sd
  <chr> <fct>       <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Q30   Não oferta     21 41.2   0.13
2 Q30   1h - 3h        10 19.6   0.13
3 Q30   Mais de 10h     2  3.92  0.13
4 Q30   50% em LA       4  7.84  0.13
5 Q30   100% em LA      6 11.8   0.13
6 Q30   4h - 5h         5  9.8   0.13
7 Q30   6h - 8h         1  1.96  0.13
8 Q30   9h - 10h        2  3.92  0.13
```